# Add control to custom base page

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to create a custom base page for my WP app. I'm doing this by creating a new `cs` class file that inherits from `PhoneApplicationPage` like this:

```
public class BasePage: PhoneApplicationPage
{
   //handle common non-visual stuff here
}
```

The problem is that I would like to add a control on every page that uses `BasePage` but BasePage has no `LayoutRoot` or any visual element that I can attach the control to. Is there a way I can add the same control to all the pages that use BasePage so that I don't have to copy/paste it every time?

**Edit**: Adding XAML based on TriggerPin's answer. I've created a new XAML file for my `BasePage.cs` but this is throwing errors in `BasePage.g.cs`:
"MyApp.MainPage already contains a definition for '_contentLoaded'" (and similar message for 'LayoutRoot' and 'InitializeComponent')

```
<local:BasePage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Template"
    x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Comment: @ebattulga - I tried that but `Children` doesn't appear in Intellisense. (Compiling results in "does not contain definition for Children...")

Comment: create Grid or container control and set to this.Content=yourGrid;

Comment: Unfortunately creating any control will require me to add that control to a visual tree. At the moment, there is no visual tree, although TriggerPin's answer seems to be a step in the right direction. Once that XAML works, then I can create the children controls.

Comment: you're getting this error because, if you go to MainPage's constructor, you'll get method `InitializeComponent();` just click on that method and press `F12`. This method contains all the declarations and definition, when you navigated to this method you'll see `_contentLoaded` is been already declareed

Answer (score 2):

Notice that by default, types derived from PhoneApplicationPage are partial

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
```

The partial definition allows you to split the class definition across multiple files. Most commonly with this type, the definition is split between a .cs and .xaml file.

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="MyProject.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

     <!-- Custom layout here -->

 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

If you make your implementation a partial class and provide base xaml code, you will be able to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've updated my question with the new XAML file I tried to create, but it's throwing an error. (I've added `partial` to the BasePage.cs file)

Comment: "MyApp.MainPage already contains a definition for '_contentLoaded'" was one of them. The others were similar but '_contentLoaded' was replaced by other methods and properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need a container which must be Panel type at least for adding your children controls. A Page is just a UserControl which couldn't add your UIElement into it directly.

Try this:

```
Panel container = // init it from your page, you must have a root element in page.
container.Children.Add(new TextBlock()); // your children control.
```

I did it in Win8.